# The proper usage (or avoidance) of "former" & "latter" when context involves a logical evaluation?

Tags: phrase-usage

In cases where a sentence involves a logical evaluation, e.g., ...

> ... Is it improper to do [this], rather than to do [that]?

...is there any convention on the usage of "former" vs "latter"?  For example, to reference [that]...

> In the case of the ______ ...

...would one use "former" or "latter" here?  At first glance, I thought "latter" since it refers to the tail-end of the referenced sentence, but then on second thought, I thought maybe I should use "former" instead because the logical evaluation resolves as `true` in the former portion of the referenced sentence, i.e., "it *is* improper, therefore...".  Or should I just avoid the usage altogether in this specific context?

Comment: *Former* and *latter* have **absolutely nothing** to do with truth values: they refer solely to the position of the concept in the sentence/passage/paragraph, etc.

Answer (score -2):

Well, I am not a professional in grammar or the English language, but I would say in this case when referring to "that" one would use the word "Latter". According to the dictionary I have and random dictionaries on the internet, the idea of "former" and "latter" simply refers to the position of each point in the previous statements, and is not subjective to the truthfulness or the relevancy of each statement. Therefore, in this case of referencing "that", give is was mentioned in the latter portion of the sentence, one would use "latter" instead of former. Hopefully this is helpful in resolving your question, and please correct me if I am mistaken

Comment: *I would say in this case when referring to "that" one would use the word "Latter"*. Thisis incorrect: **That** and **this** are a demonstrative adjectives and pronouns. They relate only to a relative position in space or time, **not** to the order in the sentence - "That *[points at a cat]* and this *[points at a dog]* must be removed from the room. Give the former [the dog] to Mr Jones and give the latter [the cat] to Miss Smith."